# How does  Pattern Matching in Scala overcome duplication that switch case causes?

Tags: oop, scala, design-patterns

**NOTE: I am asking this question out of inquisitiveness and not questioning the importance of a language feature.**

Looks to be a great feature introduced to people from imperative world of programming.
I am new to Scala and still trying to figure out where all, do its massive sets of constructs fit in and can be leveraged.

Pattern matching can definitely do stuff 100 x  better than the switch case.
but still, it is a case construct over which we use to prefer polymorphism since the time OOP came out.

*So in short what I am finding difficult to understand is, If switch case encourages duplication and we better write case related code into respective classes then How does Scala's pattern matching overcome this ?*

*We can still have classes or generic classes for various cases and again leverage polymorphism to our need.*

Comment: Short answer: [algebraic data types](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_data_type). Pattern matching is a very simple and elegant way to work with ADTs. If your code is more OO-y, polymorphism is likely to be a better fit.

Comment: "its massive sets of constructs" – don't let Martin Odersky read that. He's rather proud of the fact that Scala's set of constructs is much smaller than that of other languages. He prefers a language with a small number of powerful, composable, orthogonal constructs. By unifying e.g. functions and objects into a single construct or unifying modules, components and objects into a single construct. Or using inheritance to implement Algebraic Data Types.

Comment: @JörgWMittag: He has definitely achieved simplicity. but at the same time brought hell lot of new things for an average experienced Java developer.
and all of them are really strong features but only if we take out time and understand them one by one.
pure OOness blended with rich Functional features are really nice.
but at the same time actors,pattern matching,FP itself, are so many new things that a Java developer can easily get confused.
I get confused thinking whether to Do Scala the Java way Or jump into actors and pattern matching wherever and whenever I can.

Comment: I don't get your question. Can you explain what you mean a) by "duplication", b) by "write type related code"?

Comment: @0__: by duplication and "type" related code I mean
say if we check animalObj.getType() for dog,cat ,tiger,monkey,gorrila in a long if-else-if statement or a switch one, to make our decision everytime we have to write code for walk(),talk(),eat() etc. we will be checking type of the animal in each method, but with polymorphism, I can have classes with hierarchy and I can use method overriding to achieve this.
Thats what I have learnt for last couple of years, and now with Scala pattern matching comes which is being shown as a similar construct like switch case but much stronger.

Comment: @0__: I kind of got confused, when to go for pattern matching and when polymorphism, because I am not at all going to use it in place of switch because I dont use it at all.
So I wanted to know what is the generic use case of pattern matching when writing OO code in Scala, other than for algebraic datatypes which is also their in most of the scala books.
and agilesteel's answer clears that out for me.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It's the matter of the difference between objects and data structures.

If you are dealing with objects use the subtype polymorphism - adding new types doesn't require recompilation, retesting or redeployment of the existing ones, whereas adding a new algorithm (a method on the interface, which is at the top of the hierarchy) does.

If you are dealing with data structures use patter matching - adding new algorithms doesn't require recompilation, retesting or redeployment of the existing ones, whereas adding a new type does.

Read more about it [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20121020042747/http://blog.objectmentor.com/articles/2007/11/02/active-record-vs-objects).

Comment: See the paper "Independently Extensible Solutions to the Expression Problem" (http://zenger.org/papers/fool05.pdf) for a very insightful comparison of an object-oriented and a function decomposition of a well-known problem. The authors also identify two dimension of extensibility, namely adding behaviour and adding subtypes, and they illustrate that classical OO (behaviour) and classical FP (subtypes) approaches work well w.r.t. one of the dimensions, but not so well w.r.t. to the other. They conclude that Scala allows you to combine the two paradigms, thereby overcoming the problem.

Answer (score 4):

Patter matching is a great feature because it is easy to use.

It solves the problem of "how to bring functionality to an object system" far better than most design patterns in widely used object-oriented languages. For example there is the [Visitor pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern), which separates an algorithm from its object structure. The idea is great because it allows us to change behavior of our objects without touching their classes. But on the other side this pattern fails in overcomplexity and verbosity of notation. With pattern matching, this can be solved easily:

```
def calc(e: Expression): Double = e match {
  case Num(n) => n
  case Add(a, b) => calc(a)+calc(b)
  case Sub(a, b) => calc(a)-calc(b)
  ...
}
```

This separates the calculation of an AST from its definition and is much better to read than the polymorphic Visitor pattern.

Because patter matching is so easy, we can use it everywhere - you will find it on places which you have never thought of in most OO languages. A great example are Actors, which use algebraic data types (ADT) to communicate between each other:

```
sealed trait Message
case class Hello(name: String) extends Message
case class Bye(name: String) extends Message
case class Question(q: Symbol) extends Message

class MySelf extends Actor {
  def receive {
    case Hello(name) => println("Hello "+name)
    case Bye(name) => println("Buy "+name)
    case Question('AreYouOk) => sender answer "I'm ok"
    ...
  }
}
```

I wish you a lot of fun by implementing this with the Visitor pattern!

Comment: I don't see how the visitor pattern and actors are in any way related. The former is a way to enforce separation of concerns (here: structure and behaviour), the latter a model of concurrency.

Comment: @mhs: The domain doesn't matter. In these cases pattern matching helps to solve problems more elegant than polymorphic typing. That is what I tried to show.

Comment: I can see that ADTs and pattern matching give you a nice way of decomposing messages. However, your last sentence suggests that the visitor pattern would be a natural choice here if ADTs weren't available, and that's where I disagree. But I might just misinterpret that.

Comment: @sschaef: Is recive block of an actor same as the match block in pattern matching ?

Comment: @AmoghTalpallikar: Something like this, yes (it is a method which expects a partial function).

Comment: @mhs: What I meant with the last sentence is: "You can use the visitor pattern to achieve the same but with a lot more boilerplate"

Comment: @sschaef: Yeah, got a nice explanation here.
http://ebruchez.blogspot.in/2011/10/scala-partial-functions-without-phd.html

Answer (score 2):

I see few points where pattern matching completes OOP and allows for more modular programming.

1. When you have a big project, you want to avoid putting "too much behaviour" inside your domain classes. You can move the behaviour outside, and typically have a method which receives a class at the top of a hierarchy and matches against the children classes.
2. When you are using a specific libraries and you would like to add behaviour but you cannot modify the sources . You can also use implicit conversion for this, but in simple cases pattern matching is faster and easier.

To answer your question, I would probably say that you underestimate the code reusage pattern matching can bring: when you create a match block that creates a **PartialFunction**. If you need to reuse your pattern-matching blocks, you can use PartialFunction chaining, through the orElse method. This also brings benefits when designing a hierarchical set of handlers of a specific object, since the matches are executed in order.

Comment: "When you have a big project, you want to avoid putting "too much behaviour" inside your domain classes." Categorically false. Fowler, Martin, Evans, et al, all argue strongly for state + behavior being the foundation of OOP. Polymorphism and delegation are perfectly valid abstraction techniques for coupling state and behavior. For larger applications, the problem that usually (erroneously) leads to stripping logic from domain objects is trying to make a global unified model. The Bounded Context pattern solves this quite well.

Comment: In the OOP world I agree with what you say, but if we look to a larger world including languages that have functional feature, I disagree. You might want to read also this http://ropas.snu.ac.kr/~bruno/papers/TypeClasses.pdf

Comment: While I don't disagree with the value of functional features in software engineering (type classes being a great example of a useful construct), the truth remains that larger projects often go the wrong direction in an attempt to maintain a global unified model. Partitioning the model and its behavior into manageable pieces is the first problem to solve. Then, make decisions about traditional OOP techniques vs. "purer" FP methods. Attempting to do the latter when the namespace for domain objects is already too large is an invitation for calamity.

Answer (score 1):

Inheritance and case constructs are both valid ways to achieve polymorphism. They are good in slightly different situations. Unlike inheritance based polymorphism, pattern match is not extensible, however often you don't need it to be. Many structures in functional programming, such as Option, Either or :: can be used more concisely with pattern matches that oop polymorphism and if statements. In general any problem could be solved with either type of polymorphism. It is only a matter of elegance.

Answer (score 1):

They don't they actually do have that exact problem if you abuse them.

Just as the polymorphy by inheritance gets into problems when it causes your classes to attract all kinds of methods that don't really belong into that class.

While Java has some reasonable strong support for inheritance the switch statement is just a joke.

In Scala you have even stronger support for inheritance and the amazing pattern matching.

It's your job to pick the right hammer for your nail.